# Read specific blocks txt php and extract values

Tags: php, parsing, text

I'm doing social service, the idea is to automatize a process. I already capture other values using regex, like:

```
<?php function LeerEncabezado() {

$fh = fopen('RPREGFM_________007_001.txt', 'r') or die('lel'); $file =
str_replace(',', '',
file_get_contents("RPREGFM_________007_001.txt")); $f =
fopen("RPREGFM_________007_001.txt", "w"); fwrite($f, $file);
fclose($f); while (!feof($fh)) {
    $line = fgets($fh); 


//Intermedio
    if (preg_match('/INTERMEDIO (?<cfintermedio>[\w]+.+)/i', $line, $r1)) {
        $CFINTERMEDIO = substr($r1['cfintermedio'], 13, 8);
        echo "C.F. Intermedio: $CFINTERMEDIO";
        echo '<br/>';
    }

//Base
    if (preg_match('/BASE       (?<cfbase>[\w]+.+)/i', $line, $r2)) {
        $CFBASE = substr($r2['cfbase'], 13, 8);
        echo "C.F. Base: $CFBASE";
        echo '<br/>';

    }

//kVArh
    if (preg_match('/F.P. (?<fp>[\d]+.+)/i', $line, $r3)) {
        $anioi = substr($r3['fp'], 0, 5);
        echo "kVArh: $anioi";
        echo '<br/>';
        echo "--------------------------------------</br>";


    }

//Base promedio
    if (preg_match('/201912               (?<fp>[\d]+.+)/i', $line, $r3)) {
        $anioi = substr($r3['fp'], 8, 5); //        echo "kVArh: $anioi";
        echo '<br/>';
        echo "--------------------------------------</br>";
    }


} } LeerEncabezado();

fclose($fh);
```

And it's working until his point, I got to take 3 values from that text block, the last number in INTERM column, BASE and % M$. In this receipt, it would be 1,5,99.98%. I've used strg_replace before for, I guess ill use it for the %. So I can compare those variables with other in the same receipt.

How can I extract those value taking in mind that the 201912 it's going to change taking in consideration the year and the number of rows in MES might change? Pretty much used the blank space and the read the previous line which it's going to be the one where the 3 values are in?

```
       MES    TOTAL  PUNTA  INTERM    BASE         TOT PTA INT BAS       % M$
    201901        9               1       7        744     122 622     99.96
    201902        8               1       6        672     107 565     99.97
    201903        9               1       7        744     115 629     99.97
    201904        9               2       7        719     122 597     99.97
    201905       10       1       8                744  88 656         99.98
    201906       10       1       8                720  80 640         99.97
    201907       12       2      10                744  92 652         98.89
    201908       13       2      11                744  88 656         97.74
    201909       11       1       9                720  80 640         97.05
    201910t               1       7                624  76 548         97.56
    201910       10                       1        120      20 100     98.80
    201911        8               1       6        721     115 606     99.20
    201912        7               1       5        744     117 627     99.98
```

Comment: you could use regex, but it also simple to chop off the header, split by `\n` then loop over then split by `tab`, you then have an array on each iteration which has the columns you need https://3v4l.org/OqeGR (missing values you can check for) regex wont

Comment: I use this regex:https://regexr.com/4vmnd and it works online, but when i wanna use it on the code it just displays blank, the issue is after [\r\n], the .+ doesnt work, nothing does

Comment: its only matching one which is the whole block of text, im not sure I follow. Your table has  some items missing in the columns, regex wont match that

Comment: It only prints like 'Inicio de historico: PUNTA INTERM BASE TOT PTA INT BAS % M$'
Using this regex /MES\s+TOTAL(?<iniciohistorico>.+[\n\r]+)/i
If i try to search the next line with .+ or [\d], [0-9] its blank